# Linux bash Shell scripting : Creating command using string Append how to do that?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi I want to achieve #cat sample.txt > abc.txt

But "> abc.txt" am getting as argument.

How to cascade these two strings and execute the combined one.

### I tried the below steps

```
/home/root# export str=" > abc.txt;"    

/home/root# echo $str 

> abc.txt;

/home/root# echo "cat sample.txt $str" 

cat sample.txt  > abc.txt;

/home/root# `echo "cat sample.txt $str"`

Hello world

cat: can't open '>': No such file or directory
cat: can't open 'abc.txt;': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you trying to copy the contents of sample.txt into a file called abc.txt ?

Comment: No. This is just a sample i had given. But my intention is to combine strings and execute like $str=file.txt, Then "ls > $str". I need to join 2 strings and execute the string as command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
args="> foo"
command="date"
eval "$command $args"
cat foo
```

use of eval is not really a recommended method but sometimes it comes in handy for doing things in a quick and dirty way. I will probably get downrated for suggesting this.
Be aware of its side effects.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this from command line write :

```
cat sample.txt | tee $str
```